# plt.show() create graph 2 times

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

[Extra graph]

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/3euVn.png[1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3euVn.png%5B1%5D)

Plt.show() is creating graph 3 times while I am using plt.show() only 2 time 1 in each script.1 graph close immediately like after 1 sec

The code is as:

```
from ScriptsTogather import new
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(4, 4), num='pyplot')
plt.show(block=False)

def process_msg(msg):
         fig.canvas.
         fig.canvas.flush_events()

def read_mindray():
Read data
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try: 
        thread_mindray = multiprocessing.Process(target=read, daemon=True)
        thread_mindray.start()
        new()
    except:
        raise Exception
        print('end?')
```

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear, could you please, provide a simple and small piece of code that reproduces your issue?

Comment: @psarka I am tiring to plot 2 separate plots doing matplotlib plt.show() but instead of 2 graphs 3 graphs are showing and 1 disappear after 1 sec like the extra one disappears but I don't know why it is being showed.

Comment: We need code :) Make a small example which illustrates the failure and add it to your question.

Comment: @psarka have a look now

Comment: Much better, I have a suspicion that multiprocessing might be a culprit. Unfortunately, I cannot run your code and play around to check that. Could you try to remove all the unnecessary parts? Ideally you will be left with ~10 lines of code that I can run and check that indeed, two plots (even if empty) are show.

Comment: I managed to solve it.
I was calling plt.show() outside the fuction that was making an empty graph and them for canvass.draw it was making another graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it. I was calling `plt.show()` outside the function that was making an empty graph and then for `canvass.draw` it was making another graph.

Comment: Well done! I suppose this is how it is supposed to work - when you have a problem and try to localize it enough to be able to post here, most of the time you will find the bug yourself :)